# Usage of class libraries (dlls) - Reference or copy source

Tags: dll

I'm working on a big project for the first time and right now I'm using 15 dll's from different sources. Having all these dll's in my output directory together with my .exe is "polluting" that folder a lot.

From most of these dll's I have the source code that I could copy into a single dll of my own reducing the amount of dll's I have in the .exe folder. This looks like a tedious task though... The thing is that, every project I will make in the future will use some of these dll's because they have some very handy controls. (One of these dll's is the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com).)

What it comes down to: **Is there an easy way to either reduce the amount of dll's in the .exe folder? Is having so many dll's bad? Is copying source code into you own project an anti-pattern?**

Comment: Why do you consider all those dll files "pollution"? Would you like to reduce the number of files in the root of your application? Then why not move them all into a sub-directory?

Comment: Also consider licensing restrictions. Just because you have the sourcecode available does not mean that you are allowed to do anything you want with it. Taking the code of several libraries and merging them into a combined work *might* violate the license conditions of one or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having many DLLs is not necessarily bad. Historically, DLLs have two primary trade-offs:

1. They require more time when loading. When required they must be loaded into memory and locations mapped out to allow jumping into function locations. If a DLL is not preloaded at program start, this might mean pauses while a program is loading.
2. They require less space, assuming DLLs are centrally located *and* reused in multiple programs.

However, modern hardware nullifies these attributes. Modern computers are so fast that unless you literally have hundreds of DLLs to load, the delay will be barely noticeable, if at all. Modern storage capacities are through the roof, and the extra space required by *not* sharing libraries is generally not noticed. My Android phone has two orders of magnitude more storage than my first desktop computer (and some of the old timers around here can outdo that).

---

If you are still concerned about this, consider static linking your libraries into your program executable. *Do not simply copy the source code*.

Static linking has some potential advantages:

1. You never need be concerned about using the wrong version of a DLL.
2. If you can shrink your program down to a single file it becomes easier to make [portable](http://portableapps.com/). Note that this is neither necessary nor sufficient to make an app portable, it only makes the job easier. This may or may not be a concern.
3. Modern linkers do a pretty good job removing dead code when static linking. For example, I have seen DLLs in the tens of megabytes. Toolkits such as Qt can be that large. If you are only using a small portion of the toolkit, consider static linking instead. The linker can elide all of the unused (dead) code, bringing the combined size of your code and the library code to something much more reasonable.
4. Saving the best for last: some compilers support [whole-program optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization). This can potentially increase the run-time speed of your program, typically at a severe cost during compile time.

There is one disadvantage to static linking a large amount of code into the primary executable:

1. The initial load time is longer. The entire executable must normally be loaded into memory, globals initialized, entry logic run, etc. before `main()` can be called. This could be a lengthy delay before control passes to your program. Some larger programs (e.g. MS Office) get around this by offloading much of the program into DLLs which are loaded after `main()` is called: this allows the opportunity to display a splash (loading) screen. If you static link everything, you cannot do this.

This might not even be an issue for you. Most programs are not large enough to require a loading screen. Besides, modern hardware is lightning fast compared to the dark ages when this was a truly serious decision.

---

It is critical that you do not simply copy the source code:

1. Most, if not all, [OSI-approved licenses](http://opensource.org/licenses) will allow you to *link* code units. That is part of what makes "open source" to be "open."
2. Linking code reduces coupling compared to copying code. While the code references are the same, it is easier to upgrade to a newer library version if you can simply drop in a new static library and link away.
3. Depending on the compatibility of the licenses used in your code and each library, you might not be allowed to copy the code in and still be in compliance with the licenses. That may create a *derivative* or *combined* work, which opens several cans of worms (one can for each combination of licenses). That is a headache *you do not want*. Further discussion on the topic is dangerously close to legal advice, so I recommend simply avoiding the whole issue and going the linking route *after you read the relevant licenses*.

Comment: This is a pretty late reply, but I've done (and still doing) some more research. This is definitely a very good addition to my question and helped me in understanding some things.

Comment: Two downvoters: what do you not like? I agree that my answer does meander out of scope a little, but it does answer the question. Any ideas for improvement?